# I am getting an error when using rename() in dplyr, why does this occur?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am trying to run the following code in R:

```
`(X202112_divvy_tripdata <- dplyr::rename(X202112_divvy_tripdata
                              ,ride_id = trip_id
                              ,rideable_type = bikeid 
                              ,started_at = start_time  
                              ,ended_at = end_time  
                              ,start_station_name = from_station_name 
                              ,start_station_id = from_station_id 
                              ,end_station_name = to_station_name 
                              ,end_station_id = to_station_id 
                              ,member_casual = usertype))`
```

But the error I receive is this :

```
`Error in `dplyr::rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `trip_id` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`
```

I have googled this error to death, as you can see I have tried the solution of specifying `dplyr::rename()` however I am still receiving errors in R. I tried the above several times with and without the dplyr specification, I've tried it with plyr specifications as well.

How can I get rid of this error and rename the columns properly?

Comment: Does your dataset `X202112_divvy_tripdata` contain the column `trip_id`? What is the output of `X202112_divvy_tripdata$trip_id`?

Answer (score 0):

When you `rename` you need to place `new column name`=`old column name`:

```
plyr::rename(X202112_divvy_tripdata,
                              trip_id=ride_id )
```